# Changing individual text colour in Label Expression using Python in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, arcgis-10.7, formatting

I'm basic at Python and I would like to change a single value colour to red, in this case the 6.36 value.

[image]

I'm using this code:

```
[Nazwa] + "/" + [PPW]  + "/" + [DPW]
```

So I wanted to change the colour of [DPW] to red. I was also thinking about using string, due to summing up the values before, don't know why.

```
str( [Nazwa] ) + "/" + str( [PPW] )  + "/" + str ( [DPW] )
```

Comment: This information is in the help file [here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/formatting-tags-available-in-arcmap.htm).

Comment: Thanks, but in fact the info there is wrong. I used their expression and I had errors, answer below is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing this:-

```
[STATE_NAME] +  " "  + "<CLR red='255'>" + [POP2000]  + "</CLR>"
```

[image]

You can follow the below documentation for a better understanding.

[Specify text for labels](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/text/specify-text-for-labels.htm)